# Calculate the diagonal of a cube

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, solid-geometry

Calculate the diagonal of a cube, knowing that if it is increased by $ 2 $ cm, the total area will increase $ 32 $ $ cm ^ 2 $

Attemp: Let $x$ be the initial sidelength of the cube. Then the diagonal will be $\sqrt3x$ and the total area will be $6x^2$. We see that $\frac{6x^2}{(\sqrt3x)^2}=2$ is a constant value. Then $\frac{6x^2+32}{(\sqrt3x+2)^2}=2 <=> \sqrt3x=1$. The diagonal is $1$.

Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if all your reasoning is correct, but your algebra is off in the final step.
$$\frac{6x^2+32}{(\sqrt3x+2)^2}=2 
\\ \implies 6x^2+32=2(3x^2+4\sqrt 3 x+4)
\\ \implies 32=8\sqrt 3 x+8
\\ \implies 8\sqrt 3 x=24
\\\implies \sqrt 3 x=3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $d$ is the diagonal of the cube and $V$ the area, and $a=\frac1{3\sqrt3}$, then $V=ad^3$. This is where you went wrong, since you assumed that cubes are $2$-dimensional. So, if $d_0$ is the original diagonal, $d_1$ the new, we know that $$d_0+2=d_1$$ $$ad_0^3+32=ad_1^3$$$$d_0^3+96\sqrt3=(d_0+2)^3=d_0^3+6d_0^2+12d_0+8$$$$6d_0^2+12d_0+(8-96\sqrt3)=0$$Can you solve for $d_0$ from here?

Comment: The question explicitly states 'area', not volume, and uses units of cm$^2$, so using $6x^2$ for the total (surface) area is correct.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So am I correct?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah. Where I'm from, area refers to measure, and surface area is different.